# How to store both public and internal users using identity 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

I have an application, which contains public and internal users.

- public user: register users via form, FaceBook or Google.
- internal user: those who are in charged for manage content. They belongs to one or many roles.

Currently, both two kind of users are stored in AspNetUsers tables. The public users only has one Role, namely Public User, and assigned to user when they success to register. The internal users can have any roles if assigned.

I quite concern that somehow public one can be assigned some roles and performs action in the system.

Could you please tell me how to eliminate this problem?

Should I separate two kind of users into distinct tables?

Comment: You are concerned that the person who administers your users will assign internal privileges to a public user? Your question is not too clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could you please tell me how to eliminate this problem?

If the only difference between those two kind of users is their roles, then just use a flag column `IsPrivate` in your users table. After that in role management page make sure you always deal with users that have column `IsPrivate == true`. You can go further by creating separate classes `PublicUser` and `PrivateUser` that derive from `IdentityUser`. And use [Table Per Hierarchy](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph) (`IsPrivate` will be used as discriminator).

In your `DbContext` you'll have two `DbSet` one for `PublicUser` and another one for `PrivateUser`. The latter one should be used for managing user roles.

> Should I separate two kind of users into distinct tables?

No. If the only difference with the two kind of users is just the role they are attached then use one table and make sure to put on it a discriminator as I said above. If there exist other differences between them than just attached roles, then you may look at [Table Per Type](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt) or [Table Per Concrete](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines).

Comment: Thank you CodeNotFound. If I do as your sugesstion, I only have to guarante that no customer is assigned to any roles that belong to internal system. This could be better other than create another table to store customer. Anw, sorry for my late reply. Thank you again!